# Prove by Induction: $1- \frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{3}- \frac{1}{4} + \ldots + \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ is always positive

Tags: proof-writing, algorithms, induction, proof-explanation

How do you prove by induction that $1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\ldots+\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ is always positive.

The base case works out and the inductive step is n=k, so $1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\ldots+\frac{(-1)^k}{k}$ holds true for the statement. I am stuck on the n = k+1.

if any one can give an idea, it would help alot.

Comment: $ \frac{1}{2n-1}- \frac{1}{2n} > 0$

Comment: HINT: separate even from odd $n$

Comment: I suspect the final term in your sum should be $\cdots -\dfrac{(-1)^{n}}{n}$ or  $\cdots +\dfrac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$

Answer (score 4):

Hints:

- Call the sum $S_n$.  You want to show $S_n \gt 0$ for all positive integers $n$
- Show it is true for $n=1$ and $n=2$
- Show that if it is true for $n=2k$ then it is true for $n=2k+1$ and $n=2k+2$
- Use induction

Answer (score 2):

Hint: you might find it helpful to divide it into the cases even/uneven.

For the case that $n+1$ is uneven it is also useful to note that $\frac{1}{n}>\frac{1}{n+1}$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$.

Answer (score 1):

Proving that $1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\ldots+\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ is always positive is equivalent to proving that:

$1+\frac{1}{3}+\dots +\frac{1}{2n-1} > \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\dots +\frac{1}{2n}$

For all $n\geq 1$

Clearly this is true when $n=1$. Assuming this is true for $n=k$, how could you show this is true for $n=k+1$?